# JavaFX Getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException selecting item in an edible ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, tableview, indexoutofboundsexception

Created an Edible Combobox, being used as a search box. When I click on an item I get a 'Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: [ fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 1, size: 0 ]'

What it should do, and it seems to do it, but with the error, is type a name in the combobox, Select a name and have that added to a table, then clear the searchbox and give it focus to accept the next name. If I comment out the line that clears the value from the combobox, "searchCB.setValue(null); // <*********** THIS CAUSES THE ERROR" I don't get the error.

TestApp.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class TestApp extends Application {
    ObservableList<TestPerson> personList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<TestPerson> searchList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        searchList.add(new TestPerson("Roger",null,"Rabbit",null));
        searchList.add(new TestPerson("Jack","The","Ripper",null));
        searchList.add(new TestPerson("Ferris",null,"Bueller",null));

        personList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ComboBox<TestPerson> searchCB = new ComboBox<TestPerson>();
        searchCB.setItems(searchList);

        searchCB.setConverter(new StringConverter<TestPerson>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(TestPerson object) {
                return object != null && object.getFullName() != null?object.getFullName():"";
            }

            @Override
            public TestPerson fromString(String string) {
                return searchCB.getItems().stream().filter(o -> o.getFullName().equals(string)).findFirst().orElse(null);
            }
        });

        searchCB.setOnAction((e) -> {
            if (searchCB.getValue() != null && !searchCB.getValue().getFullName().isBlank()) {
                personList.add(searchCB.getValue());
                searchCB.setValue(null); // <*********** THIS CAUSES THE ERROR
                searchCB.requestFocus();
            }
        });

        ComboBoxListViewSkin<TestPerson> searchComboBoxSkin = new ComboBoxListViewSkin<>(searchCB);
        searchComboBoxSkin.getPopupContent().addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, (event) -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        searchCB.setSkin(searchComboBoxSkin);

        new TestAutoCompleteComboBoxListener(searchCB);

        searchCB.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        TableView<TestPerson> listTableView = new TableView<>(personList);
        listTableView.setEditable(true);
        listTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        listTableView.setItems(personList);

        TableColumn<TestPerson, String> fullNameColumn = new TableColumn<>();
        listTableView.getColumns().add(fullNameColumn);
        fullNameColumn.setEditable(true);
        fullNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().fullNameProperty());
        listTableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(searchCB,listTableView);

        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane(vBox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

AutoCompleteComboBoxListener.java This is based on another post I found here, but was not able to get it to work as written using Generics. The toString() method wouldn't work correctly.

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestAutoCompleteComboBoxListener implements EventHandler<KeyEvent>{
    private ComboBox comboBox;
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private ObservableList<TestPerson> data;
    private boolean moveCaretToPos = false;
    private int caretPos;

    public TestAutoCompleteComboBoxListener(final ComboBox<TestPerson> comboBox) {
        this.comboBox = comboBox;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        data =  comboBox.getItems();

        this.comboBox.setEditable(true);
        this.comboBox.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                comboBox.hide();
            }
        });
        this.comboBox.setOnKeyReleased(TestAutoCompleteComboBoxListener.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
            caretPos = -1;
            moveCaret(comboBox.getEditor().getText().length());
            return;
        } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
            if(!comboBox.isShowing()) {
                comboBox.show();
            }
            caretPos = -1;
            moveCaret(comboBox.getEditor().getText().length());
            return;
        } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
            moveCaretToPos = true;
            caretPos = comboBox.getEditor().getCaretPosition();
        } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DELETE) {
            moveCaretToPos = true;
            caretPos = comboBox.getEditor().getCaretPosition();
        }

        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT || event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT
                || event.isControlDown() || event.getCode() == KeyCode.HOME
                || event.getCode() == KeyCode.END || event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
            return;
        }

        ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for (TestPerson row: data) {
            if(Arrays.stream(TestAutoCompleteComboBoxListener.this.comboBox
                            .getEditor().getText().toLowerCase().split(" ", 0)).allMatch(row.getFullName().toLowerCase()::contains)) {
                list.add(row);
            }
        }

        String t = comboBox.getEditor().getText();

        comboBox.setItems(list);
        comboBox.getEditor().setText(t);
        if(!moveCaretToPos) {
            caretPos = -1;
        }
        moveCaret(t.length());
        if(!list.isEmpty()) {
            comboBox.show();
        }
    }

    private void moveCaret(int textLength) {
        if(caretPos == -1) {
            comboBox.getEditor().positionCaret(textLength);
        } else {
            comboBox.getEditor().positionCaret(caretPos);
        }
        moveCaretToPos = false;
    }
}
```

TestPerson.java class

```
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TestPerson {
    private StringProperty firstName,
                            middleName,
                            lastName,
                            suffix;

    public TestPerson() {this(null, null, null, null);}
    public TestPerson(String firstName,
                      String middleName,
                      String lastName,
                      String suffix) {
        init();

        this.firstName.set(firstName);
        this.middleName.set(middleName);
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
        this.suffix.set(suffix);
    }

    private void init() {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(null);
        this.middleName = new SimpleStringProperty(null);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(null);
        this.suffix = new SimpleStringProperty(null);
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set((StringUtils.isBlank(firstName)?null:firstName.trim()));
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName.set((StringUtils.isBlank(middleName)?null:middleName.trim()));
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set((StringUtils.isBlank(lastName)?null:lastName.trim()));
    }

    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix.set((StringUtils.isBlank(suffix)?null:suffix.trim()));
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty middleNameProperty() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix.get();
    }

    public StringProperty suffixProperty() {
        return suffix;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        String joined = Stream.of(firstName.get(), middleName.get(), lastName.get(), suffix.get())
                .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        return joined;
    }

    public StringProperty fullNameProperty() {
        StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(getFullName());

        return new SimpleStringProperty(getFullName());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getFullName();
    }
}
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: [ fromIndex: 0, toIndex: 1, size: 0 ]
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:171)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:243)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ListViewBehavior.lambda$new$57(ListViewBehavior.java:292)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:239)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:110)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:383)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1451)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:282)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:246)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:176)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3897)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: What happens if you don't build your `TestPerson` class around null? I would use a default value of `""` for `String` over null.

Comment: Where did you learn how to use `SimpleStringProperty` like you use it?

Comment: `searchCB.setValue(null)` What happens if you don't set this to `null`?

Comment: [mcve] please .. (no external references, nothing unrelated - table is irrelevant here as are the tons of properties of the data).

Comment: btw (and as @Sedrick already noted): your fullNameProperty is wrong in creating a new property on every call (nobody can listen to it if it's constantly changing :). Also, representation decisions don't belong into the data class, that's the task of the view. As to the combo: the IOOB seem to happen on selection (f.i. when navigating the popup) mostly not on typing + enter. Note that value == selectedItem, so you are changing the value while being notified of a change (which always is a suboptimal idea).

Comment: @Sedrick I have tried using "", and also an empty Person Class and still had the same error. As for learning about the SimpleStringProperty. Trial and error, this was the only way I could get the concat of the other properties to display in various tables.

Comment: I would suggest you look up a class with only JavaFX properties in it to see how things should be done. I have done a lot of tutorials, and I have never seen anything close to what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

Got it to work by enclosing the searchCB.setValue(null) in Platform runlater.

```
Platform.runLater(() -> searchCB.setValue(null));
```

thanks to Przemysław Długoszewski-Tamoń in another thread for the idea.